# Convert to PDO type mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask for assistance on how to convert the code below to PDO type especially the mysql_fetch_array. I can make it work properly using this code but I want to convert to PDO.

```
 <?php

    $query = "SELECT * from name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $cols = 6;
    echo "<table>";
    do {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cols; $i++) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if ($row) {
                $name = $row['fname'];
    ?>
                    <td>
                    <table>
                    <tr valign="top">
                    <td>
                    <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name[]" value="' . $name . '"/>' . $name . "\n"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>   
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
    <?php
            } else {
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }
    } while ($row);
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you can read more at http://php.net/pdo.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT * from name";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();

// Start your html col/row setup

// Loop through your cols

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For your example it's not necessary to 'prepare' however it is a good practice when you start passing values to your query.

Comment: I found a little bit of problem while using the code. Since I will display the data in a checkbox form after looping, i cannot get the data of other records instead the last record on the checkbox is only what i can get always. but using mysql_fetch_array i could select anything from checkbox and i count get the value of it. any suggestion?

Comment: i tried   $row = $find_all_service_tags->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but it return an empty result

Comment: If you are making a fetchAll(), then all the results will be localized as an array: `$results = $find_all_service_tags->fetchAll(PDO_FETCH_ASSOC)` then you can step through the $results array.